# Bbone render behaviour / toggling

Tags: events, backbone.js, render

Some extremely simple problem for those experienced with backbone,
but still, an answer here would very helpeful. Not looking for an functional answer, but more about what's really happening on this specific example.

With the following code (some simple add/remove from favorite)

```
render: function() {
    $(this.el).html(this.model.get('name'));
    $(this.el).append("<span class='unfav'>remove</span>");
    $(this.el).append("<span class='fav'>add</span>");
    if( this.model.get("selected") == true ){
        $(this.el).addClass("selected");
    } // Should we really need to have an 'else' conditions here that removes the clas :( ? sound weird to me.
    return this;
}
```

**Full code here http://jsfiddle.net/eHAfY/3/**
(thanks to @cymen for the codebase)

After adding an element,

Don't get why the item gets changed when I click on 'Add', and does not when I click on remove : if there is a condition that have effect when true, why it is the class' still here when false ?

Comment: It sounds like the view isn't getting rendered again. Have you confirm it is? What event are you binding to for the view to be rendered (in other words, we need a more complete example)?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the initialize part, which, in my understanding by having a change in it, should do what's expected.

Comment: So yeah, if I console.log something for both addToFavorite and removeFromFav function, render is called

Comment: If you add an `else $(@el).removeClass("highlight")` does it fix it? Seems unlikely but I can't run this to try it (not quite clear to me how your rendering works).

Comment: I followed the backbone' railscasts tuts; now getting a little further. With else, as you mentioned, the class is removed. But then why is the class added ? That's a very slight thing for me, can't get it all : in my mind the render part 'updates' the page's element, so this only 'if' should be enough

Comment: I agree but we need a jsfiddle or similar posted example. You can fork this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Gd2Rs/ to get Backbone in there and use your compiled coffeescript. I took a guess in the dark and it turned out to be a solution but why isn't clear to me without a full working example to play with.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eHAfY/3/

Comment: my (maybe dumb) point is, if it changes (click on 'add') the aspect of the element first, why the item does not get changed (click on 'remove') when the condition's not true ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your render method wipes its inner HTML with `$(this.el).html(...);` which is what render methods are usually expected to do.

With `$(this.el).addClass("selected");` you modify the external container only when `model.selected` is true, and your view has no way to know that it should remove this class when the condition is false.

Comment: I get the difference, thanks a lot. I there another pattern to follow for this kind of bahaviour, or is it regular do do it that way ?

Comment: @Ben I try to avoid direct manipulations of the elements and let the templates take care of the html side of things. But if you're comfortable with it, go ahead, you just have to remember that your views are responsible for the container states.